# I was writing in Kaggle notebook and found this error "module 'TensorFlow' has no attribute 'gfile' " tensorflow==2.6.4

Tags: python

I saw a solution like

- Find **label_map_util.py** line 137.
- Replace **tf.gfile.GFile** to **tf.io.gfile.GFile**

**but I can't find label_map_util.py file in Kaggle**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: how can I Replace tf.gfile.GFile to tf.io.gfile.GFile in kaggle notebook?